# Pass jobjectArray from JNI to Java crash on Android API 21/22 but work on API 19

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I use follow code to handle JNI array in Android and JNI.

However I found return "jobjectArray" cannot complete on API 21/22 (Android 5.0) but works on API 19. (Android 4.4) 
(*cannot complete* mean it return on JNI part but it hang and no response on Java)

Here is the pseudo code I try to implement in my Android App.

```
jobjectArray Java_com_test_Simplejni(JNIEnv* env, jobject thisObj)
    jclass localClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/Object");
    jclass objClass = reinterpret_cast<jclass>(env->NewGlobalRef(localClass));
    args = env->NewObjectArray(len, objClass, 0);
    return args;
}
```

The java part function as follow:

```
     String[] Simplejni();
```

The error message as follow:

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: attempt to return an instance of java.lang.Object[] from com.test.Simplejni
```

Please advise any suggestion how to investigate this issue, thank you.

Update: 20150427

- I try to simpreturn empty jobjectArray which works in Android 4.4 but failed in Android 5.0 (with the same code)
- My IDE is Android Studio

Comment: Post your actual code.  And check **every** return from calls to methods such as `FindClass` - don't just blindly continue without checking for errors as JNI is **very** unforgiving.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thx for responds. I have tried to reduced my code as post code here, only return empty object. But the point is it works in api19 but failed after api21. Any idea how I check this?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/alexcohn/Pass-jobjectArray-from-JNI-to-Java) works like charm on my Nexus 5 with Lollipop 5.1. I doubt if your IDE could cause problems, but just in case, try to import this project and rebuild it. Note that the APK and SO files are uploaded, so that you can compare their behavior with the ones you build locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to solve this:
you just replace `java/lang/Object` with your java object class on API 21+, for example,
 `jclass localClass = env->FindClass("com/example/YourLocalClass");`,
From the logs, we can know the object class is not the instance of yourJavaLocalObject class.